# How to run something embarrassingly parallel in Slurm?

Tags: slurm

I want to translate my script to take advantage of Slurm's memory management. Specifically, if I run the following bash script, I run out of memory:

```
#!/bin/bash

for x in 1 2 3; do
  for y in a b c; do
    run_program $x $y &
  done
done
```

This is because each instance of `run_program` takes up about 30G and I have about 250G available. I want to make it so that each instance of `run_program` is added to the Slurm queue with a request for 30G of memory. The behaviour I want is for the first 8 instances to run (because they fit), and the 9th one starts as soon as the first one finishes.

How do I get the behaviour I want?

Comment: Send to SLURM each of the executions in a different job with the proper requierement (30G of memory per job, mostly).

Comment: @Poshi Ok, so does this mean using `srun` or `sbatch`? If the latter, can I avoid making an individual script for each call to `run_program`?

Comment: It means to use the command you usually use to send jobs to queues in your system. Probably it will be `sbatch`. Check the `--wrap` parameter.

Comment: `--wrap` looks like exactly what I need, thanks. Totally new to Slurm and the distinction between `sbatch` and `srun` still gets me sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) command to do that easily:

```
parallel sbatch --wrap \"run_program {1} {2}\" ::: {1..3} ::: {a..c}
```

It will submit 9 jobs like this:

```
sbatch --wrap "run_program 1 a"
sbatch --wrap "run_program 1 b"
sbatch --wrap "run_program 1 c"
sbatch --wrap "run_program 2 a"
sbatch --wrap "run_program 2 b"
sbatch --wrap "run_program 2 c"
sbatch --wrap "run_program 3 a"
sbatch --wrap "run_program 3 b"
sbatch --wrap "run_program 3 c"
```